# Finding a functional Selenium IDE locator for a checkbox

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I am trying to "check" a select all checkbox on a webpage. I am using "Select target in page" but the "click" function does not do anything (it basically skips the step), and the "check" function  produces error: "Element is not a toggle button"

I only know how to use IDE, but am willing to learn other workflows if there is a better solution.

**This is the full xpath of the element I need to click on:**

`/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/kat-checkbox//div`

**But the select target function pulls this:**

`/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/kat-checkbox`

**How can I select the div within this element?**

**HTML for desired element:**

```
<div part="checkbox-check" role="checkbox" class="checkbox" tabindex="0" aria-checked="false" aria-disabled="false">  </div>
```

[The select target function highlights this entire area. I am unable to only highlight the checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2AcP.png)

[This is a photo of what Chrome shows on "inspect" for the element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0LAG.png)

> I have tried using ChroPath to find the xpath for the element. It says this: "*This element might be inside iframe from different src. Currently ChroPath doesn't support for them.*"